# SQL Join Query - Choose specific entry first, otherwise choose NULL

Tags: sql, join

I'm sure this has been answered before, but I can't find it!

#### Table - Booking B

```
Customer    Product
Tim         Milk
Bob         Milk
```

#### Table - Product P

```
Customer    Product     Description
Tim         Milk         This is Tim's Milk
NULL        Milk         This is Anybody's Milk
```

I want to join the tables and get the following output (showing all columns in the example for simplicity):

```
B.Customer    B.Product   P.Customer     P.Product    P.Description
Tim           MILK        Tim            MILK         This is Tim's Milk
Bob           MILK        NULL           MILK         This is Anybody's Milk
```

So, the query should lookup to see if there is a specific customer related product first, and if so, use it, otherwise use the generic product...

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
   SELECT B.Customer, B.Product,
          ISNULL(C.Customer,P.Customer) Customer,
          CASE WHEN C.Customer IS NULL THEN P.Description
               ELSE C.Description END Description
     FROM B
LEFT JOIN C ON C.Product = B.Product and C.Customer = B.Customer
LEFT JOIN P ON P.Product = B.Product and P.Customer IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess we need to join twice: First on cusotmer and product, then on product only

```
SELECT
  B.Customer,
  B.Product,
  IFNULL(Pfound.Customer,PnotFound.Customer) AS P_Customer,
  IFNULL(Pfound.Product,PnotFound.Product) AS P_Product,
  IFNULL(Pfound.Description,PnotFound.Description) AS P_Description
FROM B
  LEFT JOIN P AS Pfound
    ON B.Customer=Pfound.Customer
    AND B.Product=Pfound.Product
  LEFT JOIN P AS PnotFound
    ON B.Product=PnotFound.Product
    AND PnotFound.Customer IS NULL
```

Comment: Edge case: if Customer specific is found but Description is nullable and NULL, it will take it from the other record.

Comment: @Richardakacyberkiwi I understood this to be the intention: Have the "most valid" description.